# How rename a checkbox with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I want to change the caption and the method's name of some Checkbox that I'm doing in a new sheet. The code that I have so far is:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", _
Left:=Cells(fil_1, col_1).Left - 11.25, _
Top:=Cells(fil_1, col_1).Top, _
Width:=Range("A1").Width, Height:=Range("A1").Height
'Caption:=""
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
Set ole = ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
ole(1).Name = "New Name"
ole(1).Object.Caption = "New Caption"
```

Or to make it easier, **simply modifying your example**:

```
set newCheckbox = Sheets("Sheet1").OLEObjects.Add "Forms.CheckBox.1", _
Left:=Cells(fil_1, col_1).Left - 11.25, _
Top:=Cells(fil_1, col_1).Top, _
Width:=Range("A1").Width, Height:=Range("A1").Height
'Change name and caption
newCheckbox .Name = "New Name"
newCheckbox .Object.Caption = "New Caption"
```