# Excel VBA: Automatic naming of ComboBoxes and their Change() procedures

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have more then 2x 200 ComboBoxes in my worksheet

1. How can I name them for example in a for loop like:

   *ComboboxA1* to *ComboboxA200*
2. How can I generate all Combobox_Change() procedures automatically?

   *Private Sub ComboBoxA  1 to 200_Change()*

   *End Sub*

Comment: See similar post on renaming controls here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30046386/how-rename-a-checkbox-with-vba/30046579#30046579

Comment: Why do you have so many comboboxes?

Comment: because I need for every person one ComboBox to choose from a list of different tables which contain certain data. Unfortunately there are a lot of persons

Answer (score 0):

You could just use one combobox, possible in a userform.If you have a bunch of dropdowns in each cell, you could use data validation, instead of comboboxes.

Anyway, this is the code you can use to loop through each combobox and rename it.

```
Sub LoopAndRename()
    Dim CtRl As Object, x
    x = 1
    For Each CtRl In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        If TypeName(CtRl.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
            CtRl.Name = "Combo" & x
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Next

End Sub
```